# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que 10 rectangulos puedan caber en un JPanel usando Math.random?

Tags: java, java-ee, bluej

¿Cómo podría hacer que los rectángulos generados por métodos Math.random sean visibles todos en un JPanel? Hasta ahora llevo el código así:

```
public class rects extends JPanel {

     public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    rectangulos(g);
    }
    public void rectangulos (Graphics g){
    int x=1;
    while(x<=10){
    g.setColor (Color.blue);
    g.drawRect((int) Math.random(),(int) Math.random(),(int) Math.random(),(int) Math.random());
    x++;  }   }   
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Punto 1");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(new rects());

        frame.setSize(500, 400);

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido Victor. Si no me equivoco estás intentando dibujar 10 rectangulos de forma aleatoria dentro de un jPanel de 500x400 ¿no?

Comment: 500x400 es un ejemplo, lo que necesito es que los rectangulos se contengan en cualquier tamaño que se le asigne al JPanel pero no sé como.

Answer (score 1):

---

Saludos Victor Manuel.

### Analicemos un poco...

Analicemos primero el método `Math.random()`. Según la [documentación de Java para el método Math.random()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()):

> Retorna un valor `double` con un signo positivo, mayor o igual
>   a 0.0 y menor que 1.0 (...)

Hasta este punto, nos damos cuenta que tenemos un número entre 0.0 y 1.0, en tu caso, tu requieres que el rango de números generados sea mayor que eso, para lograrlo tendríamos que multiplicar ese valor generado (entre 0.0 y 1.0) por un **valor máximo (max)**.

Por ejemplo:

```
int max = 5; // nuestro valor máximo (excluyente)
int value = (int) (Math.random() * max);
```

El ejemplo anterior nos retornará un valor aleatorio entre **0** y **4**, ¿por qué no incluye el **5**? Eso se debe (y cómo indica la documentación) a que el número generado por `Math.random()` es **mayor o igual a 0.0** y **menor que 1.0**, es decir, se multiplicará por valores entre **0.0** y **0.9**, pero **nunca** por **1.0**.

En caso de que necesites un rango distinto, por ejemplo, un rango de valores generados entre **20** y **50**, simplemente tendríamos que restar el **valor mínimo** al **valor máximo** (para que el número generado no se salga de los límites) y luego sumar el **valor mínimo (min)** al final de la operación:

Por ejemplo:

```
int min = 20; // nuestro valor mínimo (incluyente)
int max = 50; // nuestro valor máximo (excluyente)
int value = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
```

En el ejemplo anterior, obtendremos un valor aleatorio entre **20** y **49**, el **50** sería excluído, pero nuestro valor mínimo **sí** sería incluido.

### Ahora sí, a lo que vinimos...

Volviendo a tu pregunta, buscas dibujar 10 rectángulos dentro de un `JPanel` con una dimensión de **w * h**, donde **w** es la anchura y **h** la altura.

Para obtener las dimensión de nuestro `JPanel` utilizaremos el método `getWidth()` para su anchura y `getHeight()` para su altura, ambos métodos que nos son brindados por la clase `JPanel`.

Con esto, ya tendríamos el **valor máximo** que necesitamos para nuestra operación (el **valor mínimo** no lo necesitaremos debido a que éste valor debería ser **0**, el cual corresponde a la esquina superior izquierda de nuestro componente y por ende, se omite de nuestra operación).

En cuánto al método que utilizaremos para dibujar nuestros rectángulos, tenemos lo siguiente:

```
g.drawRect(int x, int y, int width, int height);
```

Para ubicar nuestros rectángulos aleatoriamente, debemos hacerlo por separado, la coordenada **x** (que se relacionará con la anchura de nuestro `JPanel`) y la coordenada **y** (que se relacionará con la altura de nuestro `JPanel`).

```
int x = (int) (Math.random() * getWidth());
int y = (int) (Math.random() * getHeight());
```

Con esto ubicaremos los rectángulos por todo el `JPanel`, sin embargo, se debe tomar en cuenta que las coordenadas están relacionadas directamente con las dimensiones de los rectángulos, y si deseamos que esos rectángulos se mantengan totalmente **dentro** de nuestro `JPanel` tendríamos que tomar en cuenta sus dimensiones, es decir, **restarlas** del **valor máximo** de nuestra operación:

```
int w = 25; // anchura del rectángulo de ejemplo
int h = 25; // altura del rectángulo de ejemplo

int maxW = getWidth() - w; // anchura del JPanel - anchura del rectángulo
int maxH = getHeight() - h; // altura del JPanel - altura del rectángulo

int x = (int) (Math.random() * maxW);
int y = (int) (Math.random() * maxH);

g.drawRect(x, y, w, h);
```

Y de este modo, nuestro rectángulo será dibujado dentro de las dimensiones correctas de nuestro `JPanel`.

En caso de que las dimensiones (anchura y altura) de nuestros rectángulos **también** deban ser generados aleatoriamente:

```
int w = (int) (Math.random() * anchura_maxima_deseada);
int h = (int) (Math.random() * altura_maxima_deseada);

int maxW = getWidth() - w; // anchura del JPanel - anchura del rectángulo
int maxH = getHeight() - h; // altura del JPanel - altura del rectángulo

int x = (int) (Math.random() * maxW);
int y = (int) (Math.random() * maxH);

g.drawRect(x, y, w, h);
```

Donde la `anchura_maxima_deseada` es la anchura máxima que tendrían los rectángulos (puedes usar `getWidth()` para que sea el máximo del `JPanel`) y `altura_maxima_deseada` es la altura máxima que tendrían los rectángulos (puedes usar `getHeight()` para que sea el máximo del `JPanel`).

Comment: Muchas gracias, añadí un pequeño bucle para que se generaran los 10 rectángulos y funcionó. ¿Se podría tomar lo mismo para hacer, por ejemplo, 10 circulos, solamente cambiando el drawRect, por un drawOval?

Comment: Hola, Victor, claro, sí que se puede, solamente que ya necesitarías evaular **altura** y **anchura**, puesto que se trata de círculos, esa **anchura** y **altura** pasarían a hacer una sola variable, la cual es el **radio**.

Comment: Además, recuerda que si la respuesta te ayudó, márcala como respondida.